# How to escape a backslash in R?

Tags: r, backslash, stringr

I'm working in R and having troubles escaping the backslash. I am using the library `stringr`.

```
install.packages("stringr", repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
library("stringr")
```

I would like to do `str = str_replace_all(str, "\", "")`

So I tried `str = str_replace_all(str, "\\", "")` but it won't work.

What should I do?

Comment: @paul-fournel your solution doesn't work (anymore?) - `gsub("([\])","", "C:\subfolder")` throws the unrecognized escape error.

Comment: "C:\subfolder" is not a valid String to start with. If you exectute just this part in the terminal, you will have the same error

Comment: @joran I emailed Achim Zeileis and you'll be in the next release of the `fortunes` package.

Comment: @csgillespie, would you consider re-opening this question? The question linked as already having the answer does provide an indirect answer. However it takes a little bit of thinking to figure out that if using `str_replace_all` or `gsub`, the string is converted twice, requiring `\\\\ ` as input to get `\ `. The answers here explain just that.
Maybe the question title should be changed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found a solution that works

```
str = gsub("([\\])","", str)
```

Comment: As per my comment, using `"\\\\"` as a pattern will work as well (with either `gsub` or `str_replace_all`.

Comment: `gsub("\\", "", str, fixed=TRUE)` would also work. You just need to remember that in R, `\\` is only one character. Try the following: `x <- "my\\strin\\g\\with\\slashes"; print(x); cat(x)`.

Comment: In RE, \\ match \. As you need scape every \ to R understand it as \, you need use `gsub("\\\\","", str)`.

Comment: @paul  This code line will work for regular backslashes, but strings like "1\2" get replaced by "1\002", also "5\7" get replaced by "5\a". Why it is so?

Answer (score 7):

Use `Hmisc::escapeRegex` and `Hmisc::escapeBS` which automatically escapes backslashes and other regex special characters.

Comment: Not even `Hmisc` will let you completely `escapeBS`, because ultimately BS is inescapable (especially in programming, and `rep('especially', 2)` in R).