# gsub("BLAH", "", "BLAH\WHAT") won't let x have a backslash?

Tags: regex, r

I'm doing some batch string clean up and a lot of the entries look like this:

```
"ABC\Company Co."
```

Which causes weird errors, and I can't seem to remove the backslash.

For example, try entering this into your console:

```
gsub("BLAH", "", "BLAH\WHAT")
```

and you get:

```
Error: '\W' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""BLAH\W"
```

I know that it's thinking `\W` is a command.. I'm actually suprised that gsub's 'interpreting' `x`, since `x` is just the string I want to sub out.  I don't get why gsub cares what's actually in `x`, just that it should replace `"BLAH"` with "" within `"BLAH\WHAT"`...

The obvious solution would be to remove the \ from the string ahead of time.

```
gsub("\\", "", "BLAH\WHAT")
```

But then you get the exact same error message!

Thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: It's not `gsub`.  `x <- "BLAH\WHAT"` won't work either.

Comment: You need to escape it because when specifying a string "\" is the escape character. So your last argument should be "BLAH\\WHAT"

Comment: No. It's thinking "\W" is ctrl-W which is not an accepted character. See `?Quotes`. This would do what you expected: `gsub("BLAH", "", "BLAH\\WHAT")
[1] "\\WHAT"`

Comment: I'm receiving the data from an outside source.  So unfortunately what you're suggesting to do is exactly what I'm asking HOW to do.  The string is already "BLAH\WHAT", and I need to convert it programatically to either "BLAH\\WHAT" or just "BLAHWHAT"

Comment: If you made a reproducible example this would be easier. You would find that a file containing \W would look like it was read in as "\\W"

Comment: Could you clean up the data outside of R?

Comment: The above scenario is exactly the same as what I'm dealing with in R Studio, so I don't know how I can make it more reproducible?  If I can make gsub remove the backslash to a list of strings (or even a single string) then I'm golden.

Comment: No I cannot modify the outside source, it's from our core database

Comment: Post what the file looks like when viewed in a text editor. Then post the code you used to read it in. How could that be any simpler?

Comment: When I try to read in a file that has a string with a backslash, R converts the backslash to a double backslash. So `ABC\Company Co.` becomes `ABC\\Company Co.`

Comment: Well RODBC must be keeping it.  Anyway, the how im getting the data is irrelevant, point is the string managed to keep a backslash, how do i get rid of it?

Comment: Im not reading from a csv its from an access database and i cant post that

Comment: I hate to say this, but it might be a good idea to post a small screenshot (!!).  It's hard to see how it's possible even to generate a string that R would print as `"ABC\Company Co."`.  Not saying it's impossible, but it seems *extremely* odd ...

Comment: It sounds like you're able to get the data into R in some capacity.  Does `x` contain the string and if so, can you post the output of `dput(x)`

Comment: Sorry for the delay-- I did a dput on the string and it turns out it *is* as others have mentioned, there really is two backslashes, so really the string is like "BLAH\\WHAT"

Comment: That being said, if I go: gsub("\", "", "BLAH\\WHAT"), or "\\" or even "\\\" it still doesn't let me get rid of the backslash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
gsub("\\\\", "", "BLAH\\WHAT")
```

which gives

```
[1] "BLAHWHAT"
```

To produce one backslash, you need to escape it using a `\`. Thus, `"\\\\"` produces two backslashes, which matches the two inside `"BLAH\\WHAT"`.

See these related questions:

[How to escape a backslash in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879204/how-to-escape-a-backslash-in-r)

[How to escape backslashes in R string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806501/backslash-in-r-string)