# Remove leading backslash from string R

Tags: r, string, escaping

Here is the string:

```
> raw.data[27834,1]
[1] "\xff$GPGGA"
```

I have tried advice from the following two questions, but with no luck:

[How to escape a backslash in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879204/how-to-escape-a-backslash-in-r)

[How to escape backslashes in R string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806501/backslash-in-r-string)

Does anyone have a different solution from the above questions that might help? The ideal solution would be to remove the `"\xff"` portion, but for any combination of letters.

Comment: Perhaps `gsub('.*([^A-Za-z].*)', '\\1',"\xff$GPGGA")#[1] "$GPGGA"`

Comment: Works great, thanks. Any documentation with further examples of specifying characters in such a way?

Comment: Please do provide the examples, patterns in your original dataset so that it can be tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no backslash in that string. The displayed backslash is an escape marker. This and other features about entry and display of "special situations" are described in the `?Quotes` help page.. You've been given one regex rather elliptical approach to removal. Here are a couple of other approaches .... only some of which actually succeed because the `\ff` is the first "character" and it's not really legal as an R character:

```
 s <- "\xff$GPGGA"
 strsplit(s, "")
#[[1]]
#[1] NA

Warning message:
In strsplit(s, "") : input string 1 is invalid in this locale

 substr(s, 1,1)
#Error in substr(s, 1, 1) : invalid multibyte string at '<ff>$GP<47>GA'
 gsub('.*([^A-Za-z].*)', '\\1',"\xff$GPGGA")#[1]
#[1] "$GPGGA"
 ?Quotes
 gsub('\xff', '',"\xff$GPGGA")#[1]
#[1] "$GPGGA"
```

I think the reason that the regex functions don't choke on that string is that regex is actually a system mediated process whereas `strsplit` and `substr` are internal R functions.

@RichardScriven posts an example and when I tried to replicated it, I get yet a different example that shows the mapping to displayed characters is system specific. I'm on OSX 10.10.1 (Yosemite)>

```
cat('\xff')
ˇ
```

(I left off the octothorpe (#) that I would normally out in.)

Comment: This point might be further supported by the output from `cat("\xff")` which is �.

Comment: Nice. It's all making sense now.