# Getting R CMD check to understand backslashes

Tags: r, package-development

I'm writing a package of functions I use all the time, one of which is basically a short wrapper for `setdiff`:

```
"%\\%" <- function(A, B) setdiff(A, B)
```

so `1:6 %\% 4:6 == 1:3`.

Documenting this seems to be a struggle. Here are the relevant parts of my `my_package-infix.Rd` file which are throwing up issues:

```
\alias{\%\\\%}
\usage{A \%\\\% B}
```

When I run `R CMD check my_package_0.1.0.tar.gz` I get warnings:

```
* checking for code/documentation mismatches ... WARNING
  Functions or methods with usage in documentation object
  'my_package-infix' but not in code: 
  %<unescaped bksl>%

* checking Rd \usage sections ... WARNING
  Objects in \usage without \alias in documentation object
  'my_package-infix': 
  ‘%<unescaped bksl>%’
```

Taking the hint that perhaps this means I need more escapage, I tried to adjust those lines:

```
\alias{\%\\\\\%}
\usage{A \%\\\\\% B}
```

But the frustrating warning that's produced is:

```
* checking for code/documentation mismatches ... WARNING    
  Functions or methods with usage in documentation object
  'my_package-infix' but not in code:
  %\\%

* checking Rd \usage sections ... WARNING
  Objects in \usage without \alias in documentation object
  'my_package-infix':
  ‘%\\%’
```

So now we've gone from an unescaped backslash to two backslashes. Something doesn't add up... what gives? The relevant part of the [`.Rd` parsing manual](https://developer.r-project.org/parseRd.pdf) (2.2.1) doesn't offer much help:

> The backslash \ is used as an escape character: \\, \%, \{ and \}
>   remove the special meaning of the second character. The parser will
>   drop the initial backslash, and return the other character as part of
>   the text. The backslash is also used as an initial character for
>   markup macros. In an R-like or LaTeX-like context, a backslash
>   followed by an alphabetic character starts a macro; the macro name
>   continues until the first non-alphanumeric character. If the name is
>   not recognized the parser drops all digits from the end, and tries
>   again. If it is still not recognized it is returned as an UNKNOWN
>   token. All other uses of backslashes are allowed, and are passed
>   through by the parser as text.

And it seems to have compiled just fine -- `R CMD build` and `R CMD INSTALL` give no errors, and when I `library(my_package)`, I can run `?"%\\%"` to pull up the proper manual page, where I get `A %\% B` under usage, as expected (when I only use a single escape in `alias` and `usage`).

I've seen some other people struggling with this but no solutions, e.g. [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-April/068752.html)  and [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Bug-in-R-CMD-check-for-in-Rd-td4654606.html), this latter by Yihui Xie, developer of `knitr` among other packages.

(PS it doesn't even `build` with an even number of backslashes in the middle since this means the percentage sign is not escaped and `%` is interpreted as a commenting character in `.Rd` files)

---

EDIT: I've gotten a little bit closer to cracking the nut (it seems).

Looking at Tables 1-3 of the [parser manual](https://developer.r-project.org/parseRd.pdf) (pages 5-7), we can see that text sent to `usage` is interpreted in an "R-like" fashion while that to `alias` is interpreted "verbatim". I'm not sure exactly what this means (despite the descriptions on pages 8-9), but I get less vitriol from `R CMD check` if I use:

```
\alias{\%\\\%}
\usage{A \%\\% B}
```

Only one warning now:

```
* checking Rd \usage sections ... WARNING
  Bad \usage lines found in documentation object 'funchir-infix':
  A %<unescaped bksl>
```

Comment: I believe [the answer is ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879204/how-to-escape-a-backslash-in-r#comment20862252_14879204)

Comment: Just as a shot in the dark, since there seems to be a problem with mismatches between different fields: have you tried using a different number of backslashes in the `\usage` and `\alias` fields?

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes, see my edit just now. not a success, but progress.

Comment: At this point I'm wont to call this a bug on the part of `R CMD check`. The package builds and installs properly, loads properly, and all of `?"%\\%"`, `1:3 %\% 2`, and the appearance in the Usage section are all exactly as I expect when I use my original idea: `\alias{\%\\\%}` and `\usage{A \%\\\% B}`. R itself doesn't seem to have any problem--it's only `R CMD check` that's got beef.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally figured out a workaround to this. Basically a bunch of nonsense -- I still contend this is a bug. But here goes:

Add a bunch of useless code to your package. Since I was getting these warnings:

> - checking for code/documentation mismatches ... WARNING Functions or methods with usage in documentation object 'funchir-infix' but not in
>     code:   `%<unescaped bksl\>%`
> - checking Rd \usage sections ... WARNING Objects in \usage without \alias in documentation object 'funchir-infix':   `%<unescaped bksl>%`
>
> Functions with \usage entries need to have the appropriate \alias
>   entries, and all their arguments documented. The \usage entries must
>   correspond to syntactically valid R code. See chapter ‘Writing R
>   documentation files’ in the ‘Writing R Extensions’ manual.

I added the following to my `.R` file (next to the main function definition for clarity to all 1 people that will ever go through my source code):

```
"%\\%" <- function(A, B) setdiff(A, B)

"%<unescaped bksl>%" <- function(){
  cat("What are you thinking? Don't use this function. See ?\"%\\%\"")
}
```

And add this to my `.Rd` file:

```
\alias{\%<unescaped bksl>\%}
```

(And kept `usage{ A \%\\\% B }` as is).

That is, give `R CMD check` what it's asking for, even if it's just a waste of text.

The wool sufficiently pulled over `R CMD check`'s eyes, my package is now fully WARNING-free B-)

Comment: Hey Mike, this looks interesting. I think we've been in touch before. Would you mind taking a look at a related problem I am currently facing? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969528/escaping-hyphen-in-s4-method-in-rd-usage-section-in-r-package-documentation