# Escape metacharacter using R's sub function

Tags: regex, r

When escaping the `$` character using R's `sub` function as in `sub('\\$', '', '$1.99')` why is it necessary to use a double back slash?

Comment: Because "\" is a metacharacter in R too, so it too needs to be escaped.

Comment: e.g http://stackoverflow.com/q/11806501/324364 or (my favorite) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879204/how-to-escape-a-backslash-in-r#comment20862252_14879204

Comment: Interesting, but it is escaped using the backslash itself?

Comment: Yes, in R strings every two backslashes equals one.