# How do I escape quotation marks in paste()?

Tags: r, shiny

How would like to print this text `<th scope="row">` in a paste function. Because I need to escape the quotation marks, I have tried this

```
paste("<th scope=\"row\">")
[1] "<th scope=\"row\">"
```

I also tried to follow the golden rule from the first comment to this question [How to escape a backslash in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879204/how-to-escape-a-backslash-in-r), i.e. adding slashes until it works. But it did not.

Comment: Use `cat()` instead of `print()`.

Comment: You've escaped them successfully, they are working just fine. As joran says, use `cat(paste("<th scope=\"row\">"))` to "see what's really there".

Answer (score 1):

Just use a combination of single quote and double quote.

```
paste("<th scope='row'>")
[1] "<th scope='row'>"
```

Regards,
Andrey