# Reading a file on a network in R

Tags: r, path

I am importing a csv file in to R using the read.csv method but get the following error.

```
The network path is "\\shared\data\abc.csv"

read.csv("\\shared/data/abc.csv",header=T)
                    or 
read.csv("\\shared\\data\\abc.csv",header=T)
```

If I use copy paste the address in the address bar in the file explorer, it opens the file but R somehow cannot read it. What's the reason? Is it because the network name starts with **"//"** instead of traditional drive name like **C,D** etc?

Comment: \ is a special character so needs escaping with another \. if you have two \ both need escaping to give "\\\\shared\\..."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879204/how-to-escape-a-backslash-in-r#comment20862252_14879204

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to escape each backslash, so for the double backslash you need four backslashes, i.e.

```
read.csv("\\\\shared\\data\\abc.csv",header=T)
```

Answer (score 2):

in addition, the below also works and should be OS agnostic:

```
read.csv("//shared/data/abc.csv",header=T)
```

when running `getwd()` note how the separator between folders is forward slash (`/`), as it is on `Linux` and `Mac` systems. 
If you use the `Windows` operating system, the forward slash will look odd, because you’re familiar with the backslash (`\`) of `Windows` folders. When working in `Windows`, you need to either use the forward slash or escape your backslashes using a double backslash (`\\`).

Answer (score 1):

Using R's built-in file system functions:

```
CSVfile <- file.path('\\\\shared', 'data', 'abc.csv')
read.csv(CSVfile, header=T)`
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do an additional step before any of the above options worked for me. I'm working from a Mac accessing a PC network attached storage which might (?) change the direction of slashes you need to put in.

1. Find correct file path that R recognizes:

> RStudio Tools--> Global Options
> Browse to folder in default working directory
> Copy this file path

2. Replace each single slash in the file path with double slashes (as noted above)
3. run read.csv function

Example:
file path copied from file: S://servername/data/raw/test.csv
file path copied from browsing to same file and what RStudio displays in working directory: /Volumes/data/raw/test.csv

read.csv("//Volumes//data//raw//test.csv")