# How to replace a string with a single backslash using gsub in R?

Tags: r, regex, string

I like to encode UTF-8 string. In my data the character are separated with `=` for the function `encoding` in R I need to separate them with `\x`

```
string <- "=2E=30=31=20=52=C3=A9=70=6F=6E=64=65=75=72"
x <-  gsub("=", "\x", string)
Encoding(x)
Encoding(x) <- "latin1"
x
```

I tried to add one, two, three backslashes to escape. Put in round and square brackets. Add quotes. Put the argument `fixed=F`. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806501/how-to-escape-backslashes-in-r-string), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879204/how-to-escape-a-backslash-in-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721008/how-do-i-deal-with-special-characters-like-in-my-regex) and still have no clue how to do it.

**Expected output:**

```
.01 Répondeur
```

When I use two backslashes like Wiktor says and check with `cat()`, there's only one backslash in the output, but it has no effect on `encoding()`, only when I change it by hand.

**Edit:**

For example when I do this, it puts two backslashes and `endcoding` doesn't work:

```
> gsub("=", "\\x", string, fixed=TRUE)
[1] "\\x2E\\x30\\x31\\x20\\x52\\xC3\\xA9\\x70\\x6F\\x6E\\x64\\x65\\x75\\x72"
```

The same with the suggestion from Aleksandr Voitov:

```
> gsub("=", "\\\\x", string)
[1] "\\x2E\\x30\\x31\\x20\\x52\\xC3\\xA9\\x70\\x6F\\x6E\\x64\\x65\\x75\\x72"
```

Comment: Tried `gsub("=", "\\x", string, fixed=TRUE)`? See [this demo](https://ideone.com/lRpoam). Are you trying to get `".01 RÃ©pondeur"` in the end?

Comment: You must use `cat()` to see the actual backslashes in the string.

Comment: So what is the expected output?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew exactly  `".01 RÃ©pondeur"` is what i want

Comment: I thought about [this solution](https://ideone.com/Rryzk7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x <- "=2E=30=31=20=52=C3=A9=70=6F=6E=64=65=75=72"  # string data
x <- strsplit(x, "=", useBytes = FALSE )[[1]]       # split string
x <- x[nchar(x) > 0]                               # remove elements with 0 character length
```

using `strtoi`

```
# convert string to integer and convert integer to raw and then to character
rawToChar( as.raw( strtoi(x, base = 16L) ) )                  
# [1] ".01 RÃ©pondeur"
```

`?strtoi` document page says

> hexadecimal constants (prefix 0x or 0X) are interpreted as base 8 and
>   16

using `as.hexmode` to cast character to hexadecimal format

```
rawToChar( as.raw( as.hexmode( x ) ) )
# [1] ".01 RÃ©pondeur"
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `gsub("=", "\\x", string, fixed=TRUE)` to replace `=` with `\x`, and then `parse` the resulting string:

```
string <- "=2E=30=31=20=52=C3=A9=70=6F=6E=64=65=75=72"
x <- parse(text = paste0("'", gsub("=", "\\x", string, fixed=TRUE), "'"))
x[[1]]
## => ".01 Répondeur"
```

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/Rryzk7).

Here is another solution based on the [`Unicode` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Unicode/Unicode.pdf):

```
> library(Unicode)
> string <- "=2E=30=31=20=52=C3=A9=70=6F=6E=64=65=75=72"
> x1 <- gsub("=", " U+", string, fixed=TRUE)
> y <- unlist(strsplit(trimws(x1), "\\s+"))
> intToUtf8(as.u_char_seq(y))
[1] ".01 Répondeur"
```

Here, I replaced all `=` with space+`U+`, and then split the string with 1+ whitespace symbols after trimming the input. `intToUtf8(as.u_char_seq(y))` creates a Unicode string from the Unicode character sequence.

Answer (score 0):

```
string <- "=2E=30=31=20=52=C3=A9=70=6F=6E=64=65=75=72"
x <-  gsub("=", "\\\\x ", string)
```

Comment: @Cath, no it puts a *single* backslash, you only see two. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/lRpoam).

Comment: Didn't tested, sorry