# Split a character string in R on a single backslash

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am trying to split a character string in R on a single backslash (`\`).

None of the following work:

```
strsplit("Joshua\Rosenberg", "\\")
strsplit("Joshua\Rosenberg", "\\\\")

strsplit("Joshua\Rosenberg", "[\]")
strsplit("Joshua\Rosenberg", "[\\]")

strsplit("Joshua\Rosenberg", "\\")
strsplit("Joshua\Rosenberg", "\\\\")
```

All relevant answers seem to pertain to two backslashes, `\\`, e.g.:

- [How to escape backslashes in R string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806501/how-to-escape-backslashes-in-r-string)
- [How to escape a backslash in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879204/how-to-escape-a-backslash-in-r)

How can you split a character string on a single backslash?

Comment: HINT: `"Joshua\Rosenberg"` doesn't contain a backslash

Comment: @HongOoi what, uh, does it contain then? :)

Comment: HINT 2: `"\\str"` doesn't contain 2 backslashes

Comment: I can grok the notion that `\` represents an escape character. I'm not sure what to do about this.